# what is difference between Hashmap and concurrent HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am new to Stackoverflow searched over google but not able to understand the basic difference between them.

Comment: Go through http://ria101.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/concurrenthashmap-avoid-a-common-misuse/. Its a broad and nice article

Answer (score 1):

The `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe, while the basic `HashMap` is not. This is explained as well in the [official documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Check the possible dup question, there's more on `ConcurrentHashMap` apart from being thread-safe.

Comment: After typing this answer, I saw your link to the dup question. I guess this question will be closed relatively soon ;)